# WPF: Convert VisualBrush to Drawing?

Tags: wpf, drawing, visualbrush

I have a VisualBrush and need this VisualBrush as a Drawing. Anyone knows how this can be done? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense, because a `VisualBrush` is unrelated to a `Drawing` (it would make more sense with a `DrawingBrush`). However, you can create a `Drawing` by using the `VisualBrush` to paint on it. Something like that should work :

```
public static Drawing GetDrawing(TileBrush brush)
{
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, new Pen(Brushes.Transparent, 0.0), brush.ViewPort);
    drawingContext.Close();
    return drawingVisual.Drawing;
}
```

(this is valid for any brush inherited from `TileBrush`, not just a `VisualBrush`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looks very promising :-)
Note that you can just set the pen to null
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, 0.0), brush.ViewPort);

Answer (score 5):

Here's the XAML version:

```
<GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,1 0,1 Z">
  <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
    <VisualBrush>
      ...
    </VisualBrush>
  </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
</GeometryDrawing>
```